# Is usefull this method Collections.unmodifiableList?

Tags: java

Let's me explain, I have been reading (incredible) about make your collections unmodifiable, take a look [encapsulate collections](https://myquacks.wordpress.com/2012/10/28/encapsulate-collection/), it's an interesting idea, but I can't imagine a practical situation for it.

Can someone explain a practical application of it?

Comment: @Dukeling ty for improve mi text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has two main advantages:

1. While coding you can make a read-only collection class without making a subclass, you can use a generic read-only wrapper on every type of collection (re-usability)
2. In the runtime you can create a read-only view of an existing collection without copying the whole collection to a read-only implementation (which is usually expensive)

The latter is often useful when you want to prevent your class users from modifying your own internal collection.

Nowadays it's also considered good design to favor [composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance), which fits this pattern nicely.

Example of 1:

```
class myComplicatedCollection<T> implements Collection<T> {
     // Code goes here

     // O no, I still have to deal with the read-only use-case.
     // Instead of duplicating almost all of my code or using inheritance I'll use this handy-dandy wrapper
     public Collection<T> readonlyVersion() {
          return Collections.unmodifiableCollection(this);
     }
}
```

Example of 2:

```
class myClass {
     private Collection<T> theData;

     // Users need to access the data,
     // but we don't want them modifying the private data of this class
     public Collection<T> getTheData() {
         return Collections.unmodifiableCollection(theData);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's really useful when you return a list that's a private member of an object, as modifying the list from outside would break encapsulation

e.g. `obj.getList().clear();` would clear the list inside the obj (asssuming getList() returns a private member), but if getList() returned a list that was passed into Collections.unmodifiableList then an exception would be thrown

Answer (score 2):

Use it any time you want to safely publish a list and/or enforce immutability.

For example:

```
// neither the reference nor the contents can change
private static final List<String> codes = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"));
```

This list can't be modified inside the class, and could be published safely:

```
// the caller can't change the list returned
public static List<String> getCodes() {
    return codes;
}
```